# Saving a couple of strings in the local storage

Tags: javascript, html, css, twitter-bootstrap, local-storage

I'm trying to save some strings in the local storage, I'm trying to do this but I get undefined in the local storage.

I'm asking the user for the players names, and then I want to store them in the local storage in order to use them again.

Here's what I'm trying :

```
const x = localStorage.getItem('playersNum');
const parentDiv = document.getElementById('player-list');
for (let i = 0; i < x; i++) {
  const newInput = document.createElement("INPUT");
  newInput.setAttribute("type", "text");
  newInput.setAttribute("class", "form-control");
  newInput.setAttribute("id", `player${i}`);
  newInput.setAttribute("placeholder", "Player's Name");

  parentDiv.appendChild(newInput);
}

//get all input elements of type text and starting id with player
const input = document.querySelectorAll("[type='text'][id^='player']");
const btn = document.getElementById('startGame');
btn.addEventListener('click', function() {
  //reset border style of all input elements
  [...input].forEach(el => el.style.border = '');
  //get all empty input elements
  let empty = [...input].filter(el => el.value.trim() == "");
  //check length
  if (empty.length) {
    //show alert
    // alert('Please fill in the players names');
    //set border style to empty input elements
    empty.forEach(el => el.style.border = '1px solid red');
  }
  else {
    window.location.assign('game.html');
    localStorage.setItem('playersNames', String(input.value));

  }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You're declaring input with `querySelectorAll`, so you need to read input as an array.

`localStorage.setItem('playersNames', String(input[0].value));`

Then, if you want all player's names you will need to iterate through the array. Also, you need to get the previous value of localStorage and append to it, since it gets overwritten every time you set it.

```
const input = document.querySelectorAll("[type='text'][id^='player']");

for (i=0; i < input.length; i++) {

    var checkForStorage = localStorage.getItem('playersNames');

  if (checkForStorage !== null) {
        localStorage.setItem('playersNames', checkForStorage + ',' + String(input[i].value))  
  } else {
        localStorage.setItem('playersNames', String(input[i].value));
  }
};
```

Comment: Thanks for your response, when I do that, I only get the first player's name, I would like to store all the players names.

Comment: I've updated my original answer, I hope it helps!

Comment: thanks, when I used this code, I get (playersNames         ,,,)